# Create link to a resource file in the browser

Tags: java, spring, rest, model-view-controller

Good evening!

I am developing a small REST server in the Spring. Faced with the following problem:

I need to do an open resource folder and send a link to the files of the following form:

http: // localhost: 8080 / myProjectName / resurses / 2.jpg

but I get to take only this type of link:

file: / D: /apache-tomcat-7.0.69/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/2.jpg

The dispatcher-servlet.xml file I added:

```
  <mvc: resources mapping = "/ resources / **" location = "/ resources /" />
```

In the controller declared method:

```
@RequestMapping("/get_photo")
public @ResponseBody
RequestUserInfoFull get_photo(@RequestBody String body,
                 HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    RequestUserInfoFull result = new RequestUserInfoFull();
    UserFullInformation usf = new UserFullInformation();
    Resource anotherResource =context.getResource("2.jpg");
    usf.setPhoto(anotherResource.getURL());
    result.setProfile(usf);
    return result;
```

---

Please help with this problem. I will be very grateful. Sorry for my English. It is terrible. And the code is also not the best .. I just started learning Spring :)

Answer (score 0):

my problem was in inccorrect spring dispatcher configuration and folder structure.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```